# R partition a sequence of given numbers into various combinations

Tags: r

Suppose we have given sequence of numbers:

```
z=c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I want to create all possible classes (of varying size) from this given sequence of numbers in the following way:

1) The most simplistic case is when the class size is 1 i.e. all class sizes are equal. In this case we have the following groups: 1-2,2-3,3-4 and 4-5.

2) When one or more class size may be equal to 2.

a) We can have 1 class with size 2 and all others of size 1 as follows: 1-3,3-4 and 4-5. Similarly, 1-2,2-4 and 4-5 & 1-2,2-3 and 3-5.

b) We may also have cases with 2 classes with size 2.
For eg.: 1-3 and 3-5.

3) When one class size is 3 and one with size 1. For eg 1-4 and 4-5 & 1-2 and 2-5.

4) Finally, we will have one case where class size is 4 i.e. 1-5.

Note that in all of the above cases, the upper limit of the previous class is equal to the lower limit of the next class (even with unequal class sizes).

Is there a way to do this in R? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: added specific implementation using `partition` package.

The way it's described, it sounds like one way to think of this as you have 5 slots with 4 ranges between them (the dashes), with 3 potential walls separating the ranges from their adjacent neighbors.

```
  | | |
1-2-3-4-5
```

You can get all the combinations by toggling each barrier, from all open:

```
   0 0 0
 1-2-3-4-5  
 one with class of sizes of 4
```

to all closed:

```
  | | |
1-2-3-4-5
one case with class sizes of 1
1-2
  2-3
    3-4
      4-5
```

So the combinations are all the binary numbers from 000 (0) to 111 (7), 8 in all, equal to 2^n, where n is the number of walls, which is the number of elements minus 2.

One approach could use pseudocode like this:

1. Take number of elements - 2 = number of binary bits to represent all solutions
2. For each number from 0 to 2^(# elements - 2), convert to binary.
3. Use the positions of the 1's to split up ranges.
4. Show all the ranges.
5. ...Profit!!!

It looks like there's at least one package in R that solves partition problems for you. Here's an implementation using that and `tidyverse` manipulations.

```
library(tidyverse)
partitions::compositions(4) %>% 
  as.matrix() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(position = row_number()) %>%
  gather(combo_num, segment_length, -position) %>%
  filter(segment_length > 0) %>%
  mutate(segment_label = paste0(position, "-", position + segment_length)) %>%
  select(-segment_length) %>%
  spread(position, segment_label)



# A tibble: 8 x 5
  combo_num `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`  
  <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 V1        1-5   NA    NA    NA   
2 V2        1-2   2-5   NA    NA   
3 V3        1-3   2-4   NA    NA   
4 V4        1-2   2-3   3-5   NA   
5 V5        1-4   2-3   NA    NA   
6 V6        1-2   2-4   3-4   NA   
7 V7        1-3   2-3   3-4   NA   
8 V8        1-2   2-3   3-4   4-5
```

Comment: Thank you. This was really helpful. I can start writing the function now (I think).

Comment: Added to answer with an implementation using the `partition` package.